# How do we make APIs with slow depedencies faster?

Tags: api, queue, microservices, latency, low-latency

Recently I have attended two different job interviews and one of the questions they made was something like this:

1- You need to create an API that will use some microservices that are very slow. Some of them respond under a few seconds (let's say 2 seconds). We have to make our best to build our API very reliable in terms of latency. What would you do to make this system work fast?

2- This led me to other questions like if I choose to cache some data, what do I have to do avoid old cache? For example, if i cached the user personal info and he just updated his profile?

3- Finally if it was not a reading operation, what do we have to do to use services that take a long time not impact the user experience? In this case imagine that it's a writing operation

How would you answer these questions?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little vague but I'll try and throw a couple of solutions out there.

Before jumping into the cache, I would first ask questions about the data set. For instance, how large is this data set and how often does the data set change? If the data set isn't large, you can probably store all of it in memory indefinitely and on updates, you can update individual records in the cache.

Of course when we say we store it in cache, we also have to keep in mind data retrieval. If data retrieval requires grabbing the data in many different ways and the data set is large, caching may not be as great as a solution. This kind of addresses the first and second question that you've posted without further information from the interviewer. This in turn is really where you need to tease out requirements from the interviewer to see if you're on the right track.

Now finally for the third question, I think the interviewer is trying to get you to write asynchronously to something like a queuing mechanism that allows user to get a quick response and your system to take its time processing it. A follow up question here may be about how long can a write take to be processed and that will lead to a series of more domain specific questions. Again, you'll have to dig into the requirements of this to see what kind of trade-offs the interviewer wants you to make because there is no silver bullet.